# Applying ng-repeat on array of objects displays [Object object]

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-routing

I have a controller that looks like this:

```
var PlayersController = function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/Players/Index').success(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $scope.players = data;
    });
}

PlayersController.$inject = ['$scope','$http'];
```

My routing looks like this:

```
var KorpenApp = angular.module('KorpenApp', ['ngRoute']);

KorpenApp.controller('HomeController', HomeController);
KorpenApp.controller('PlayersController', PlayersController);

var configFunction = function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/Players', { templateUrl: 'Players/Index', controller: PlayersController })
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}

configFunction.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];
KorpenApp.config(configFunction);
```

My view (Players/Index) looks like this:

```
<p>TEST</p>
<p>{{players.length}}</p>
<ul ng-repeat="player in players">
    <li ng-repeat="prop in player">
        {{prop}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

The console log in the player controller logs an array with 5 objects, as it should. These object contains a number of properties that I'm trying to display. However, my view only displays:

> [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

It seems everything in the view is ignored, so obviously I'm doing something wrong. I would've thought atleast the paragraph containing "TEST" would display even if there was something wrong with the players array. So my two questions are:

1. Why does my view show "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]" ?
2. Why doesn't the stuff I've put in Players/Index show?

Comment: Can you comment with your console.log(players)

Comment: The console.log shows: [Object,Object,Object,Object,Object]
And each object has properties Id, FirstName, LastName

Comment: so try to log using console.log(angular.toJson(data));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Because that's how objects are printed. If you want the json representation of this object, use

   ```
   console.log(angular.toJson(data));
   ```
2. Hard to tell. Maybe the view is not actually at this URL. Look at the Network tab of your browser dev tools, and see what is returned.

Comment: 1. Yes, but why is it displayed in my view? I can't find anywhere where I do that. In the console yes, but not in the view.

2. In the Network tab, Players/Index har a status of 200 OK, so it seems to be present.

Comment: 1. Sorry, I misread your question. I thought that was written in the console. 2. I just realized you get Players/Index to get the players (so it should return a JSON array), and the same URL to get the HTML template of the view (so it should return an html template). Fix one of the URLs.

Comment: Changing the URL for getting the players worked, so really the view wasn't at the correct URL as you initially answered. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following:

```
var PlayersController = function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/Players/Index').success(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $scope.players = data;
    });
}

PlayersController.$inject = ['$scope','$http'];
```

And in the view:

```
<p>TEST</p>
<p>{{players.length}}</p>
<ul ng-repeat="player in players">
    {{player.prop}}
</ul>
```